# Predicting Cost estimates for Construction

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I wanted to seek some thoughts on a particular problem I am facing. I wanted to check if there is a way I can use ML or some Data Science Method to predict the cost estimates.

**Problem:** 
One of the major driver of Capital Expenditure is building out datacenters. DCs are built in multiple locations and the whole construction lasts for 20 months.

Currently the process is to take cost estimates from General Contractors involved in building and do the projections for 5 yrs out on a monthly basis. For the immediate next Q, we take the next 3 months projections of cost and estimate the Q CapEx estimates.

Problem is there is a variance in what those estimates are and what the actual costs come out to be a month or two later.

I want to check if there is a way I can use ML and data to get those cost estimates.

The main data is the estimates given by the GCs month before the actual month going to next 5 years. A month later we get the actual of that month. So we have the actual month cost and estimated cost for that month prior to that month.

Each can be broken down to base level of item (wiring, etc).

**Aim:**

To predict the cost at Quarterly level based on actuals we get and estimated data for all new builds for that Q.

The variance can be caused by many things. The actual labor cost goes up if the weather goes bad. So it disrupts the schedule changes. Or some equipment didn't arrive on time later which delays things. Or some design changes happen later on the building construction and that can cause changes.

There are tonnes of reasons which can cause changes. These are not pre-defined.

So was hoping if there is a way I can still model it beforehand

Comment: @whuber Do u think u can provide some thoughts? I always cherish ur valued opinions here. Thnx